# Best way to create a trend/graph in my application

Tags: android, graph

I have currently some values in an array that I would like to display in a trend / graph ( don't know the appropriate english word)

I have been looking in Android source code to find the Gingerbread battery graph (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Settings/+/gingerbread-release/src/com/android/settings/fuelgauge/BatteryHistoryChart.java
)

That solution seem to be a little bit overcomplicated and too much for a simple and nice graph.

Can someone point me a tutorial / code sample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try AChartEngine, it's really easy to understand and set up. Comes with plenty of examples too. http://www.achartengine.org/